# What's the difference between 逼, 迫, and 逼迫?

Tags: usage, mandarin, difference, cantonese

1. Do 逼, 迫, and 逼迫 all carry the same connotation of "to force"? Is there a difference?
2. If there's a difference, when should you use each one?
3. Which is the most common to use in speaking and writing?
4. Is there a difference between Cantonese and Mandarin?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/4820.html
>
> 逼,近也。——《说文新附》
>
> 逼, means 'to approach and get close to'

~

> http://xh.5156edu.com/html3/4732.html
>
> 迫: 用强力压制 (use force to press)

~

> http://xh.5156edu.com/html5/z32m80j144802.html
>
> 逼迫: to force;to compel;to press

**逼迫**(approach and forcefully press) = '**to force/ to compel/ to press**'

It is a compound word

逼 and 迫 are very similar, but there are subtle difference

- 逼: by approach extremely close, you are in effect **pressing** the object
- 迫: by forcefully pressing, you are extremely **close to** the object

In my experience, many people use 逼 and 迫 interchangeably

I have no problem with people using 逼 or 迫 for 'press' as in '逼切/'迫切 (pressingly close = urgent)

But I object using 迫 instead of 逼 for 'approach' as in '颱風逼近' (typhoon approaching)

> Do they all carry the same connotation of “to force?”

- 迫 and 逼迫 mean 'to force' directly
- 逼 means 'to force' by extended meaning  (approaching --> pressing --> forcing)

*Cantonese only use 迫 or 逼 for 'to force'. 
We do not use the term 逼迫*

Answer (score 2):

I intuitively think you can distinguish them like: 逼 is someone force you do something, while 迫 is you have to do (have no choice but to do) something.

e.g.

我妈**逼我**写作业：My mom ***force me to*** do my homework

我**迫于无奈**，只能告诉你妈妈你没写作业：I ***have no choice but to*** tell your mom that you didn't do your homework.

---

And when you use them together, 逼迫 can be either 逼 or 迫.

In Chinese (especially ancient Chinese) some words are biased, which means **the word's meaning is the same as one part of the word** and have nothing to do with the other part. The exact meaning of these words are decided by contents.

More examples are: 园圃(tree filed & vegetable filed), 国家(country & family), 利害(gain & loss), 出入(in & out), 深浅(deep & shallow), 褒贬(praise & belittle), 悲欢(sad & happy)

But these biased combined words are mostly appears in ancient Chinese not modern. Some of them now have a fixed meaning rather than a contents based meaning. Like 国家(country only now).

These are my intuitive feelings.